# how to use draggable within modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use draggable() within modal. 
it works perfectly outside of modal but doesn't work when I use it in modal. 
Would you tell me what is the problem and how to fix this?

here is my full code. 
(I just included all CSS and script. Didn't know how to post them separately.   2017.06.14)

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
@CHARSET "UTF-8";


element.style {
width: 200px;
display: block;
top: 5442px;
left: 629px;
}
.design-dropdown {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
top: -9999px;
padding: 5px 0;
background: white;
border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
z-index: 10000;
}
.design-dropdown .divider {
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1;
cursor: default;
height: 0px;
}
.design-dropdown li {
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}
.design-dropdown ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.design-dropdown li:hover {
background-color: #DEF;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 1000px;
height: 850px;
margin-bottom: 220px

box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: animatetop;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right:2%;

}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;

}

*{

box-sizing: border-box;

}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-header {
position: relative;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 16px 20px 15px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
color: #00B8FF;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
float: right;
}



/* Modal Body */
.modal-body {
width:100%;
height:90%;
padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;

}

.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


</style>

</head>

<body>



<!-- mouse left click window -->   
<div class="grid_context_menu design-dropdown" id="grid_context_menu" style="width: 200px; display: block; top: 5467px; left: 653px;">
   <ul class="custom-menu">
      <li id="_setting" class="_setting"><span class="txt">imagemap seeting</span></li>            
   </ul>
</div>






<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-header" align="center">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>video setting</h3>
</div> 


<div class="modal-body" id="body" > 

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p >Drag me around</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>


<script>


//get dropdown on mouse right-click

$(document).ready(function(){    
     $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
   // Avoid the real one
         event.preventDefault();    
   // Show contextmenu
         $(".grid_context_menu").finish().toggle(100).   
   // In the right position (the mouse)
         css({
             top: event.clientY + "px",
             left: event.clientX + "px"
         });
         $(".custom-menu li").click(function(e){
              // This is the triggered action name
             switch($(this).attr("class")) {      
               case "_setting": 
               $(".modal").show(); 
               $(".grid_context_menu").hide(100);
               $(".close").click(function(){ 
                  $(document).on("contextmenu dragstart selectstart",function(e){
                        return true;
                    });
                  $(document).bind("contextmenu");
                  $(".modal").hide(100); })
               $(".modal").unbind("contextmenu");
               $(".modal").on("contextmenu dragstart selectstart",function(e){
                return false;
                });
               break;
                 case "_extend": alert("second"); break;
                 case "_copy": alert("third"); break;
             }

         });
     });
  });


    $( function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
} );


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("_setting");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to get dropdown on mouse right-click, then get the modal.

Answer (score 0):

First try initial draggable item then do what you want to do. it s working now. Try this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/0orxxkvf/

```
    $("#draggable").draggable();
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("_setting");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for checking the code, but its still not working. I re-posted my code. If you have have time, would you look at it? thank you.

Comment: did you look jsfiddle link which is ı sent you ?  this one : https://jsfiddle.net/0orxxkvf/   you dont have to use jquery function     $( function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
} );    use just this   $("#draggable").draggable();